# AdMob Banner will not show on iOS 7

Tags: ios, admob, adbannerview

I'm trying to integrate AdMob into an app on iOS 7 and I can not seem to get the banner to show. I have read the other questions pertaining to this issue and they don't seem to have any good information. Here is the code I'm using:

```
AdMob = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - GAD_SIZE_320x50.height, GAD_SIZE_320x50.width, GAD_SIZE_320x50.height)];
//AdMob.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - GAD_SIZE_320x50.height, GAD_SIZE_320x50.width, GAD_SIZE_320x50.height);
AdMob.adUnitID = @"MYAPPID";
AdMob.rootViewController = self;
AdMob.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:AdMob];
GADRequest *r = [[GADRequest alloc] init];
r.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"MYDEVICEID", nil];
r.testing = YES;
[AdMob loadRequest:r];
```

I've tested on simulator and on device with no luck.